# UIStatusBarStyle battery color is green

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Alright I have my UIStatusBarStyle set to white with this

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

and it's working BUT….. The status bar battery icon is **green**, how are we supposed to change that?

Comment: I thinks its not possible

Comment: @Matthias. Very funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

or

If you prefer to opt out of having view controllers adjust the status bar style—and instead set the status bar style by using the `UIApplicationstatusBarStyle` method—add the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` key to an app’s `Info.plist` file and give it the value NO.

Or

try this

1. Set "View controller-based status bar appearance" (UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance) to YES in your Info.plist. (YES is the default, so you can also just leave this value out of your plist.)
2. your class viewDidLoad method, call [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate].
3. To Implement preferredStatusBarStyle, returning the status bar style that you want for this view controller.

`-(UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle { 
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
    }`

Comment: Thank you I appreciate this but I found the answer, this is the answer though

Answer (score 18):

About the battery being green it's green only when charging the iDevice, when not charging the battery icon goes white or black according to the style of your statusbar.

Comment: ....and I never had noticed that.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.